# Action for opening edit page in admin?

Tags: wp-admin, actions

I have a function that kills the media buttons on certain custom post types. I want it to load whenever any post/ page edit page opens. What's the best action to hook this up to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `'load-post.php'` action.

Comment: Sweet. I love you.

Answer (score -1):

also try "load-post-new.php" for new pages